# Members of CimClass is different through pipeline

Tags: powershell

I would have expected to get the same "type" from both of the following commands. The second prepends the type name with "Selected."

```
>(Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk).CimClass | gm

   TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimClass

Name                MemberType     Definition
----                ----------     ----------
Dispose             Method         void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals              Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode         Method         int GetHashCode()
GetType             Method         type GetType()
ToString            Method         string ToString()
CimClassMethods     Property       Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Generic.CimReadOnlyKeyedCollection[Microsoft.M
CimClassProperties  Property       Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Generic.CimReadOnlyKeyedCollection[Microsoft.M
CimClassQualifiers  Property       Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Generic.CimReadOnlyKeyedCollection[Microsoft.M
CimSuperClass       Property       cimclass CimSuperClass {get;}
CimSuperClassName   Property       string CimSuperClassName {get;}
CimSystemProperties Property       Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties CimSystemProperties {get;}
CimClassName        ScriptProperty System.String CimClassName {get=[OutputType([string])]...
```

The second reveals a different type.

```
>Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -Property CimClass | gm


   TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
CimClass    NoteProperty cimclass CimClass=root/cimv2:Win32_MappedLogicalDisk

>$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.14409.1018
```

Comment: one thing to keep in mind with `Select-Object` is that - when you specify properties to include/exclude - **_you create a new object with those props_**. you are NOT adding/removing props ... you are making a NEW object with the specified props. it can change the basic nature of the props when they are broken away from the source object in some situations ... and you appear to have found one. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Select-Object` with the `-Property` parameter outputs an object with the selected properties.

To get a "bare" property value, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter instead.

`Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CimClass | gm`